# Как в JS получить метку с Яндекс.Карт?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Опишу кратко: на сайте есть Яндекс.Карта, на ней метки. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на метку выполнялось какое-либо действие. Как в JS повесить на эту метку обработчик событий?

```
let center = [55.75,37.62]

function init() {
    let map = new ymaps.Map(`map`, {
        center: center,
        zoom: 13
    });


    // placemark
    let smth = new ymaps.Placemark([55.74,37.72], {}, {

    });

    map.geoObjects.add(smth);
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ есть и в [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Event.html) и в [примерах Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_rollover/). Нужно просто повесить Event внутри функции init() примерно так:

```
smth.events.add('click', function (e) {
    alert('Тест')
})
```